# What does resultCode -334 mean

Tags: go, xmlhttprequest, http-post, backend, payment-gateway

im working on sending a http request message using Golang. The request message is resulting in a result code of -334. Im not sure what this value means, and somebody help

The value -334 is generated after the request message is sent to paymentology. The request can be sent, the issue is, it returns a -334 in the response message from paymentology. Im supposed to receive other information instead.

Answer (score 0):

From, what I believe to be, the [documentation for the service you are using](https://developer.sprint.paymentology.com/response-codes/):

> -334   sessionKey present and not decryptable/parsable

So you are sending a sessionKey but it's not one the service will accept. As you have not provided any code it's not really possible to suggest what you need to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for the info Brits, ill be checking on this issue relating to yr input. Very helpful.